# Method prediction() is undefined for the type Evaluation

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

I used Decision Tree Machine Learning algorithm for training and testing data using `Weka`. I used below code lines.

```
FastVector predictions = new FastVector();
Evaluation validation = classify(models[j], trainingSplits[i], testingSplits[i]);
predictions.appendElements(validation.predictions());
```

But `predictions()` method is underline and error for that is `The predictions() is undefined for the type Evaluation`.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Talking off the top of my head here, but the result of classification is usually a model, not "validation". Validation usually refers to assessing the quality of your model.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the full example. Can you provide the full set of code for this?